# neovim only highlighting sytax in files with certain extension (regardless of filetype)

Tags: vim, neovim

I have two files with identical content: `index.html.erb` and `index.html.ecr`.

Typing `:set ft?` in nvim returns `filetype=eruby` in both.

I am running a few plugins, including: `vim-rails`, and `vim-crystal`.

I have tried turning syntax off and back on again.

Here is the content of the `index.html.{erb, ecr}` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Screenshot of highlighting:

[image]

Comment: What does `:set syntax?` show for each file? (`:h 'syntax'` might help)

Comment: `:set syntax?` returns `syntax=eruby` for both files.

Comment: Have you tried a minimal `.vimrc`? More often than not it's some other plugin(s) or setting(s) you don't recall or easily spot.

Answer (score 0):

From looking in the default `eruby.vim` syntax file for neovim, it seems that `ecr` is not a recognised filetype for eruby. As well as that, while testing myself, when the file had the `ecr` filetype typing `:set ft?` showed the filetype as HTML.

Though, even though settings syntax and filetype to eruby should work, they don't as it does with other languages such as python. I belive this could be due to a bug in the eruby syntax file, or elsewhere in the *vi*s. If it is a bug in the `eruby.vim` file, the maintainer is TPope and could get contacted if need be.

Relevant part of `eruby.vim`:

```
if &filetype =~ '^eruby\.'
  let b:eruby_subtype = matchstr(&filetype,'^eruby\.\zs\w\+')
elseif !exists("b:eruby_subtype") && main_syntax == 'eruby'
  let s:lines = getline(1)."\n".getline(2)."\n".getline(3)."\n".getline(4)."\n".getline(5)."\n".getline("$")
  let b:eruby_subtype = matchstr(s:lines,'eruby_subtype=\zs\w\+')
  if b:eruby_subtype == ''
    let b:eruby_subtype = matchstr(substitute(expand("%:t"),'\c\%(\.erb\|\.eruby\|\.erubis\)\+$','',''),'\.\zs\w\+\%(\ze+\w\+\)\=$')
  endif
  if b:eruby_subtype == 'rhtml'
    let b:eruby_subtype = 'html'
  elseif b:eruby_subtype == 'rb'
    let b:eruby_subtype = 'ruby'
  elseif b:eruby_subtype == 'yml'
    let b:eruby_subtype = 'yaml'
  elseif b:eruby_subtype == 'js'
    let b:eruby_subtype = 'javascript'
  elseif b:eruby_subtype == 'txt'
    " Conventional; not a real file type
    let b:eruby_subtype = 'text'
  elseif b:eruby_subtype == ''
    let b:eruby_subtype = g:eruby_default_subtype
  endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `:set filetype=eruby.html`

Looking at the `eruby.vim` syntax file it seems that it expects a "subtype" that comes after a dot.